# Why does TaskSpawn take ints instead of void*?

Tags: c, pointers, casting, void-pointers, vxworks

For the vxWorks operating system, they provide a system library for spawning tasks:

```
int taskSpawn
    (
    char *  name,             /* name of new task (stored at pStackBase) */
    int     priority,         /* priority of new task */
    int     options,          /* task option word */
    int     stackSize,        /* size (bytes) of stack needed plus name */
    FUNCPTR entryPt,          /* entry point of new task */
    int     arg1,             /* 1st of 10 req'd task args to pass to func */
    int     arg2,
    int     arg3,
    int     arg4,
    int     arg5,
    int     arg6,
    int     arg7,
    int     arg8,
    int     arg9,
    int     arg10
    )
```

You can see how limited this is compared to something like std::thread.
Normally, I could pass in the appropriate arguments based on the entry function.

---

Given that this is a C function, I was curious if there was a reason that vxWorks choose to have arguments 1-10 be ints instead of void pointers.

If they were void pointers, I would be able to pass in any type, and then cast it back inside the entry function.

If I wanted to pass a pointer of `struct foo` into the entry function given to taskSpawn, could it be converted to an integer, and then back to the appropriate pointer?
**Based on the design of this function, am I forced to use globals?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you will find that on VxWorks an integer is the same size as a pointer, and the common practice is to cast between them.  So if you want to pass a pointer via `TaskSpawn`, you can pass it as `(int)ptr`.

No, this isn't portable C, but it is apparently normal practice on this platform with this function.

Comment: Hmm, that sounds like pretty dirty code. Relying on implementation details without need is bad style. **Iff** one has to pass a pointer as an integer (there are good reasons in some generic functions), `intptr_t` and his sibbling `uintptr_t` should be used. That not only is guaranteed to hold a pointer, but also clearly states "this object might hold a pointer".

Comment: @Olaf: That's not relevant here, because the person asking this question is using a vendor API which cannot be modified.

Comment: Just take my comment as a - well - comment. It is relevant judging the quality of code and how well it is maintained by the vendor. (I know VxWorks). I did not state the code is broken, though as I'm very well assume aware the code does works onm that platform. But there is a lot such code which is more problematic and this might be read by other people who, too.

Comment: It should also be remembered that this API has been around for a long, long time, and any modifications would potentially cause problems (or at the very least new warnings etc) in long standing, proven code, that is in wide use in risk-adverse and slow-changing industries